# Disable Terminal man page shortcut on Catalina

Tags: terminal, keybindings

I recently upgraded to MacOS Catalina and when I am in IDEA IntelliJ, if I press `Command + Shift + M` the OS opens the Terminal program and attempts to load the man page for whatever I had highlighted in the editor at that time, as described [here](https://osxdaily.com/2014/06/24/launch-command-man-page-terminal-help-menu/).

This is very annoying because I already have that keyboard shortcut mapped to something else in IntelliJ that I use quite frequently. How do I disable this shortcut?

I tried looking in the Terminal program's preferences but I don't see any keyboard shortcut options there.

Comment: That's also valid for `Command`+`Shift`+`A`, which triggers search in man page when you actually want to open "run action"

Answer (score 15):

If you open Terminal -> Services -> Services Preferences there are some options there for enabling/disabling global keyboard shortcuts.

[image: services preferences menu]

Then you can disable this at Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> Open man Page in Terminal

[image: settings screenshot]

Comment: It might help that "open man page in Terminal" is in the section "Text"